# Google FormResponse

Tags: google-chrome

I created QR codes for students to scan to sign in and out of the washroom, and used a sheet in the excel page to copy the pre-filled form response link and changed the part to say "FormResponse" but when my students scan the QR codes, it makes them click a link before recording their response - is there anyway to make this so once the code is scanned, that's it? One step?